# Forgot Guidewire Product Designer Password

Tags: guidewire

The default password for the GW Product designer is gwgw, I changed the password and not able to recollect it and not able to login Product designer.

[image]

I've gone through the productdesigner.war file for any datasource or properties file but couldn't find any. I believe the product designer uses jetty server to deploy the war file so looked for any web.xml and went through the jar files for default source but xmls and proprties files are not there. Any help to reset PD password or finding the datasource would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the folder named "pd-config" in the path "PolicyCenter/ProductDesigner/"

Then, close your product designer application and launch it again.

Now you can login with default credentials and then you can reset the password as you wish.

Comment: Thanks @ArunMAK , The "pd-config" folder got created at the root directory instead of "PolicyCenter/ProductDesigner", after deleting it I was able to login with default password.